# Can a Docker container run as a Jenkins build node with both Java 11 and Java 8?

Tags: docker, java, jenkins

I have a customer who is excited about the idea of Docker containers as Jenkins build nodes, but a few of their pipelines still have dependencies on Java 8. Can a Docker container have Java 11 and Java 8, use 11 to run as an agent but 8 to execute a pipeline?

Comment: why not run separate docker containers for each type of pipelines?

Comment: I think this question belongs to stack overflow

Comment: @kofemann StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question, it's a DevOps question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can install java 11 in one location, and use java 8 as default. Something in the line (pseudo file):

```
# Dockerfile
FROM: …
COPY java11.tar /opt

RUN yum/apt install java8
# make sure java8 in default path

CMD [“/opt/java11/bin/java -jar jenkis-slave.jar”]
```

Keep in mind, that final container will be ~400MB

Comment: Ah, I was going to ask if the container will still function as an agent but I see the final CMD will take care of that. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work, though. There is no standalone jenkins slave .jar anywhere on the jenkins server. ??

Comment: Are you using Swarm agents?